# Mathematical notations are wrongly displayed

Tags: equations

I type a series of mathematical equations in Latex, but output is wrongly displayed (They are highlighted in yellow), how could I fix this problem.

[image]

The packages used:

```
\documentclass[letter,dvips,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{oldlfont,epsfig,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,color}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

and the corresponding codes in yellow

```
\begin{aligned}
    \Omega^{i}_{k\mid {k}} &=  \Omega^{i}_{k\mid {k-1}}+ |\mathcal{N}|\sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j} (H_k^j)^T (R_k^j)^{-1}H_k^j  \notag\\
    q_{k\mid {k}}^i &=  q^{i}_{k\mid {k-1}}+ |\mathcal{N}|\sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j} (H_k^j)^T (R_k^j)^{-1} z_k^j
    \end{aligned}
```

Comment: The culprit seems to be the `oldlfont` package. It seems to turn `\mathcal` into a switch like `\small` and not into a macro like `\emph{...}`. Why do you load that package? From what I could find on the internet, this package is for legacy documents for backward compatibility.

Comment: Besides `oldlfont` which is the source of the problem, also  `epsfig` and `latexsym` are obsolete; the former should be replaced by `graphicx`, the latter removed altogether (`amssymb` replaces it).

Comment: While we're at it: `amssymb` internally loads `amsfonts` (see [What does each AMS package do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32102/35864)), so you can drop the call to `amsfonts`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get this behaviour because you load the package `oldlfont` which restores the old font behaviour of LaTeX 2.09.

As a result in your example `\mathcal` doesn't take an argument any more, but acts as a switch (much like `\small` still does). So in order to keep its effect limited to the `N` we need to say `{\mathcal N}` instead of `\mathcal{N}`.

As far as I can see, `oldlfont` is really only there to support legacy documents and should not be used in new documents you write. (In in [mathrm doesn't change back pdflatex (pre-install of texmaker)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201796/35864) [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) writes: "`oldlfont` [...] is a package to be used ***only*** for typesetting documents written with LaTeX2.09, that's been obsolete for more than twenty years.")

You had better drop `oldlfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \Omega^{i}_{k\mid {k}} &=  \Omega^{i}_{k\mid {k-1}}+ \abs{\mathcal{N}}\sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j} (H_k^j)^T (R_k^j)^{-1}H_k^j \\
    q_{k\mid {k}}^i &=  q^{i}_{k\mid {k-1}}+ \abs{\mathcal{N}}\sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}} \pi_{L,k}^{i,j} (H_k^j)^T (R_k^j)^{-1} z_k^j
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to minimize the example, fine; but then remove `amsfonts`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the suggestion. It is done.